# Real analysis - Series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Hi guys could you help me with this:

proof if $\sum a_{n}^{2}$ convergs then $\sum \frac{a_{n}}{n}$ convergs absolutely.

i tried:

if $\sum a_{n}^{2}$ convergs then exists m $\geq n\geq n_{0}$ ; given $\varepsilon > 0$

so.  $| a_{n+1}^2 + a_{n+2}^2 + ... + a_{n+m}^2| < \varepsilon $

i was goona use triangular inequality but it doesn't helps. 
and i can't keep continue. Maybe i've taken the wrong way to solve this problem.

Comment: It's been asked quite a few times. Hint: try either Cauchy-Schwarz or the AM-GM inequality.

Answer (score 0):

If $m,n\in\mathbb N$ and $m\geqslant n$, then$$\sum_{k=n}^m\left|\frac{a_k}k\right|\leqslant\left(\sum_{k=n}^m{a_k}^2\right)\left(\sum_{k=n}^m\frac1{k^2}\right)$$by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Now, apply Cauchy's convergence test.

Comment: Not even a need for that last step: summing from 1 to $n$ (without Cauchy slices) is enough, by monotone convergence. (A series of non-negative terms converges iff it is bounded).

Comment: @ClementC. Indeed.